# PHP SQLite3 query ignore first word

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 for a local database for a movie catalog. It displays alphabetically as I want. Everything works great however I would like to disregard the word "The" at the beginning of film titles when it is displayed. So as an example if a title in the database is "The Great Gatsby" instead of displaying this under T alphabetically I want it listed under G. All results are listed on one page. Is their a query to the DB that can return the results in the order like this?

```
$db = new SQLite3('Movie Database.db');

$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Movies");

$list = '';
while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

$id = $row["id"];
$MovieTitle = $row["MovieTitle"];
$MovieYear = $row["MovieDate"];
$MovieRes = $row["MovieRes"];
$FileName = $row["FileName"];
$Summary = $row["Summary"];
$Genres = $row["Genres"];
$PictureLocation = $row["PictureLocation"];
$Rating = $row["Rating"];
$ReleaseDate = $row["ReleaseDate"];


//BUILD THE MOVIES RESULT OUTPUT
$list .= '<div class="box">
          <div class="movie">
          <div class="movie-image"><span class="play"><a href="movielist.php?movie='.$FileName.'"><span class="name">'.$MovieTitle.'</span></span><img src="'.$ThumbnailPic.'" alt=""></a></div>
          <div class="rating">
          <p><a href="movie-info.php?movie='.$id.'">RATING: </a>'.$Rating.'</p>
          <div class="stars">
          <div class="'.$StarGraphic.'"></div>
          </div>
          <span class="comments"></span></div>
          </div>';

  }
```

Comment: The simplest solution will be to change the way you save titles: `Great Gatsby, The` You also can add special field with title without `the` to sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and simple solution which may suffice would be to use :-

```
SELECT *,replace(MovieTitle,'The ','') AS sortby FROM Movies ORDER BY sortby;
```

The may have the disadvantage that `THE` elsewhere from the title could have an impact upon the sort. (Note space after `The` so as not to affect words that include **the**).

The result would be like the following :-

[image]

If you wanted to ensure that only the first **The** is ignored then you could use something like :-

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN substr(movietitle,1,4) = 'The ' 
    THEN substr(movietitle,5)
    ELSE movietitle
END AS sortby
FROM movies
ORDER by sortby
```

You could also not have the extra column by ORDERing on the result(truncation) directly. The equivalents to the two previous queries could be :-

```
SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY replace(MovieTitle,'The ','');
```

and

```
SELECT * from movies ORDER BY CASE WHEN substr(MovieTitle,1,4) = 'The ' THEN substr(MovieTitle,5) ELSE MovieTitle END;
```

Comment: Fantastic MikeT. How would I incorporate this into a query with a LIKE and a GLOB? The only other querys I have are similar to this `SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieTitle LIKE 'a%'` and `SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieTitle GLOB '[0-9]*'`

Comment: So if you wanted to get all movies that started with an "A" or a "T" or a GLOB (if they begin with number).

Comment: @Micha just add the WHERE clause between the FROM and ORDER clauses e.g. `SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN substr(movietitle,1,4) = 'The ' 
    THEN substr(movietitle,5)
    ELSE movietitle
END AS sortby
FROM Movies WHERE MovieTitle LIKE 'a%'
ORDER by sortby;` and `SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN substr(movietitle,1,4) = 'The ' 
    THEN substr(movietitle,5)
    ELSE movietitle
END AS sortby
FROM Movies 
WHERE MovieTitle GLOB '[0-9]*'
ORDER by sortby;`

Comment: hey man. I really appreciate the help. A FEDEX to Australia containing beer is in order! Really thanks dude. You saved the day.